# Pass parameters to anonymous array with loop in Perl

Tags: arrays, loops, perl

I have issues understanding this Perl module, I am very new to Perl, where main logic is within the `ExternalLibrary::registerJob` and it is executed as listed below, the mentioned `ExecutionBlock` is a black box for me and all I do know I can list several `unitFunc()` within `tasksequence`.

```
tasksequence=>[
        $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB1'),
        $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB2'),
        $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB3')
      ]
```

The module part, this is the template pattern we should use:

```
sub myFunc{
  my %args=@_;
  my $ic = $args{'initialcontext'};
 
  my $basetasksequence = [
    new ExecutionBlock(
      initialcontext=>$ic,
      tasksequence=>[
        $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob')
      ]
    )
  ];
 
  my $runtasksequence = [
    new ExecutionBlock(
      initialcontext=>$ic,
      tasksequence=>$basetasksequence
    )
    ->errCallBack($ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::logger', kind=>"J", status=>"F",RunTaskSequence=>$basetasksequence))
  ];
 
  return { tasksequence=>$runtasksequence };
}
```

I want to modify that to so I can pass multiple `jobName`s there, the `registerJob` can accept `jobName` as parameter, this is a hint for me.

```
$ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>$jobName)
```

I however do not know how to loop this properly or even how to name the problem so I could lookup the problem and read on the topic. Trying to understand the whereabouts are a bit harder to me.

I can get the `jobName` from a loop similar to this:

```
my @res= $ic->DBHandler::sql(sql=>$statementQuery);
foreach my $list(@res){
  $jobName = $list->{'JOB_NAME'};
}
```

But I am not sure how to go about combining this together, whether I can run the loop within the array like this?

```
sub myFunc{
  my %args=@_;
  my $ic = $args{'initialcontext'};

  my $basetasksequence = [
    new ExecutionBlock(
      initialcontext=>$ic,
      tasksequence=>[
      my @res= $ic->DBHandler::sql(sql=> $statementQuery);
      foreach my $list(@res){
        $jobName = $list->{'JOB_NAME'};
        $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>$jobName)
      }
      ]
    )
  ];

  my $runtasksequence = [
    new ExecutionBlock(
      initialcontext=>$ic,
      tasksequence=>$basetasksequence
    )
    ->errCallBack($ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::logger', kind=>"J", status=>"F",RunTaskSequence=>$basetasksequence))
  ];

  return { tasksequence=>$runtasksequence };
}
```

I think I would need another function to return the whole array and then assign it to `tasksequence`, but I do not know how to preserve the required form (`$ic->unitFunc()`) and pass it correctly.

Comment: The name of the language is Perl, not PERL; it's not an acronym.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question can be summarized as follows:

> I have an array of rows `@res`. Each row is a reference to a hash with a `JOB_NAME` element.
>
> I want to do the following such that each row results in a task with `jobName` given by the value of the row's `JOB_NAME` element:
>
> ```perl
> new ExecutionBlock(
>   initialcontext=>$ic,
>   tasksequence=>[
>     $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB1'),
>     $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB2'),
>     $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>'JOB3')
>   ]
> )
> ```

`[]` creates an array, so that's what we're going to do.

```perl
my @rows = $ic->DBHandler::sql(sql=>$statementQuery);

my @task_sequence;
for my $row (@rows) {
  push @task_sequence,
    $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>$row->{JOB_NAME});
}

new ExecutionBlock(
  initialcontext=>$ic,
  tasksequence=>\@task_sequence
)
```

I would use the following simpler solution:

```perl
new ExecutionBlock(
  initialcontext=>$ic,
  tasksequence=>[
    map { $ic->unitFunc('ExternalLibrary::registerJob', jobName=>$_->{JOB_NAME}) }
       $ic->DBHandler::sql(sql=>$statementQuery)
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me on right direction. Having difficulties naming thing properly.